# Can I bypass ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION?

Tags: c#, file, winapi, mutual-exclusion

I have the following C# code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileStream fileStream = null;
        try
        {
            // read from file or write to file
            fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\FileLock.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to copy the file "D:\FileLock.txt" to another location using the following C (WinAPI) code:

```
CopyFile(_T("D:\\FileLock.txt"), _T("D:\\temp\\FileLock.txt"),FALSE);
```

But I get ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION (as expected).

Is there anyway I can bypass this? (i.e. copy the file under these conditions) --without modifying the C# code

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If there's a way to bypass file sharing, then someone's just going to ask fo a way to disallow bypassing file sharing, and someone else's just going to ask for a way to bypass even that, etc. You end up in a never-ending loop.

Comment: Are you sure you can't change the C# code to FileShare.Read?

Comment: Let me rephrase. It there a way to copy a file that's in use?

Comment: Yes, use FileShare.Read on the source file.

Comment: Ask yourself why the file was locked in the first place

Comment: Maybe the process "forgot" to unlock it. Maybe I want to unlock it without killing that process.

Comment: The last time I remember someone trying to override mechanisms that protect system integrity a nuclear power plant blew up, and Europe got its share of nuclear fallout. You are free to learn from mistakes others have made.

Comment: Maybe you should fix the other program

Answer (score -1):

If you can change the C# code, then this should work (changed the OP code to use FileShare.Read):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(@"D:\FileLock.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Upon further research, it would seem that this is possible by writing a driver and using some low level functions.

Comment: Please don't. The sharing mechanism is designed to protect the integrity of both the system and apps running on it. Please go back and tell us why you need to "bypass a sharing violation", what program isn't playing nice, and why modifying the source is out of the question.